# Error in python code of undefined variable , but i have also define a function with this name

Tags: python-3.x, variables, undefined, pylance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhScf.jpg)

In this code where I put startTask in self.ui.line it showing that i haven't defined it but in lower i define a function with this name .

class Main(QMainWindow):

```
def __init__(self):
    
    super().__init__()
    self.ui= Ui_ProtonMainGUI()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
    
    self.ui.Startbuton.clicked.connect(self,startTask); 
    self.ui.Exitbutton.clicked.connect(self,close)

def startTask(self):
    self.ui.movie=QtGui.QMovie('../G.U.I Material-20220312T045851Z-001/G.U.I Material/ExtraGui/Jarvis_Gui (1).gif')
    self.ui.CenterGIF.setMovie(self.ui.movie)
    self.ui.movie.start()

    self.ui.movie=QtGui.QMovie("../download/download (1).gif")
    self.ui.rightJarvis.setMovie(self.ui.movie)
    self.ui.movie.start()
```

Comment: When you're asking for help, you’ll get more/better answers if you don’t post screenshots or photos. Cut & paste the text directly into the message.

Why?
1. It's easier for people to read it.
2. It allows those reading it to cut & paste the text, making it easier to work on solving your problem.
3. It makes it searchable, so that someone can find this thread when Googling for information in the future.
4. A screen reader can't read a picture which limits access to some in our community.

Answer (score 0):

You may forgot to type t in (startTask) parameter in 372 line
try to type it correctly